# Couldn't match type Synonym with Either

Tags: haskell, types, pattern-matching, either

I'm a beginner learning Haskell. But not so sure how `Either` works in pattern matching.

Here is my code:

```
type Rank = Either Pip Court
type Pip = Int
type Deck = [Card]
data Card = Joker | Card Suit Rank
data Court = Ace | Jack | Queen | King deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)
data Suit = Hearts | Diamonds | Clubs | Spades deriving (Show, Ord, Eq)

snap :: Card -> Card -> String
snap Joker Joker = "SNAP"
snap (Card s1 r1) (Card s2 r2)
    | r1 == r2 = "SNAP"
snap _ _ = "..."
```

GHCi told me that `Couldn't match type ‘Court’ with ‘Either Pip Court’`, can anyone help me with it?

Comment: Can't reproduce. That code loads fine in GHCi on my system.

Comment: What do you try in GHCi?

Comment: what part of the script does GHC complain about?, post the full error

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to create a card with something like `Card Hearts Jack` instead of `Card Hearts (Right Jack)`. (Similarly, `Card Hearts (Left 3)`.)

Comment: @chepner I think I misunderstood the meaning of either which failed to match the data type, especially when type is so important in such a language:)

Comment: @assembly.jc I tried the the card type but forgot Left / Right in Either type. :)

Comment: @Escutche0n Another way to think of it is to remember that every value belongs to exactly one type. `Jack` belongs to `Court`, so it can't belong to `Either Pip Court`, but `Right Jack` can. (This applies to polymorphic values as well; `3` is not a single value, but a general name that can be inferred to be `3::Int, `3::Float`, etc as necessary.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Either` isn't simply a union of types; it's a *tagged* union, which means every value has to explicitly specify which "side" of the type the wrapped value occurs on. Here's an example, (with a `Show` instance derived for your `Card` type):

```
*Main> Card Hearts Jack

<interactive>:3:13: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘Court’ with ‘Either Pip Court’
      Expected type: Rank
        Actual type: Court
    • In the second argument of ‘Card’, namely ‘Jack’
      In the expression: Card Hearts Jack
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = Card Hearts Jack
```

`Card` expects an argument of type `Either Pip Court`, but you gave it a plain `Court` value. With an explicit wrap:

```
*Main> Card Hearts (Right Jack)
Card Hearts (Right Jack)
```

The same applies to creating a numbered card:

```
*Main> Card Hearts 3

<interactive>:5:13: error:
    • No instance for (Num Rank) arising from the literal ‘3’
    • In the second argument of ‘Card’, namely ‘3’
      In the expression: Card Hearts 3
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = Card Hearts 3
*Main> Card Hearts (Left 3)
Card Hearts (Left 3)
```

You don't need to change the definition of `snap`, because there is already an `Eq` instance for `Either` as long as both wrapped types have `Eq` instances themselves; it considers any `Right` value unequal to any `Left` value, and matching `Right` or `Left` values are equal if the wrapped values are equal.

```
*Main> snap (Card Hearts (Right Jack)) (Card Hearts (Left 3))
"..."
*Main> snap (Card Hearts (Right Jack)) (Card Spades (Right Jack))
"SNAP"
```